# accessing hidden value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've got a hidden value in my jsp:

```
<html:hidden property="user.strRegistered" value="user.strRegistered"/>
```

How can I access it in my js file? I have:

```
var regChk = $('[name="user.strRegistered"]');
alert(regChk);
```

but that doesn't work. I've also tried these two:

```
var regChk = $('user.strRegistered');
alert($('#user.strRegistered').val());
```

but they both come up as undefined.

The value in the html is correct though, and when I look, it shows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user.strRegistered" value="yes">
```

Comment: The first one should work. Did you remember `document.ready` etc.

Comment: a) what adeneo said
b) you can also use    alert(document.getElementById('YOUR hidden field id').value);

Comment: What's coming up in `alert`, by the way?

Comment: @AndrewDunai, The alert shows: undefined

Comment: What is the output if you alert `el.length` instead of `el.val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing developerwjk response as I can't comment.

When you use:

```
  $('user.strRegistered');
```

You are trying to find a type of element "user" with the css class strRegistered.

If you use:

```
$('#user.strRegistered');
```

You are trying to find an element with id "user" and the css class strRegistered. The dot (.) on a jQuery selector means you want an element with a certain class.
If you want to use dot (.) on a jQuery selector, remember to escape it with two backslashes. So for that to work you would use:

```
$('#user\\.strRegistered');
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. . . I needed it to be var regChk = $('[name="user.strRegistered"]').val();

Answer (score 0):

Only old non-standard versions of IE (i.e. IE 6) let you access an html tag by `name` attribute with `document.getElementById` (which is used behind the scenes by JQuery's `$()`).  In fact, I may even be remembering that incorrect, as IE 6 might not even let you do this.

For anything standards compliant, you need an `id` attribute to use `document.getElementById`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user.strRegistered" name="user.strRegistered" value="yes">
```

Now the question is how to get your framework's `<html:hidden` to give this thing an `id` attribute....You didn't tag the framework you're using, so I can't help you on that.